# Allowing only domain root without slash in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My goal is to have script in www.example.com/dir/index.php with some extra files and allow access to it via www.example.com/dir but forbid anything else.

As close as I am is to have access from www.example.com/dir/, but it bugs me how to do it without trailing slash.

Here is my .htaccess file (in directory "dir"):

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All

<FilesMatch '^(|index.php)$'>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
</FilesMatch>
```

I can access it from www.example.com/dir/ and from www.example.com/dir/index.php. For any other file in the directory it gives 403 as I want it, but it also gives 403 for www.example.com/dir - how do I change that?

EDIT:
My .htaccess in root contains only 1 line:

```
DirectorySlash On
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all of your existing code and place this code in `/dir/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dir/

RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]

RewriteRule !^(index.php)?$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: I have put it at the beginning and it still gives 403 for www.example.com/dir - it looks like [L] somehow is ignored.

Comment: Did you place it in `/dir/.htaccess` and there is no other rule there?

Comment: I have tested with exactly this code this code and it worked fine. In your root .htaccess you should have `DirectorySlash On` line to add a trailing slash.

Comment: I have your 4 lines, then mine 6 and had added "DirectorySlash On" to root .htaccess - still not working - can it be Apache configuration?

Comment: What happens when you visit these URIs 1. `http://doman.com/dir` 2. `http://doman.com/dir/index.php`

Comment: I'm getting 404 twice.

Comment: Ok if you rename this .htaccess then what happens with both URLs?

Comment: Then www.example.com/dir redirects to www.example.com/dir/ and it displays script from index.php

Comment: Ok bring back `/dir/.htaccess` and comment out `RewriteRule !^(index.php)?$ - [F,NC]` rule. Try both URLs again

Comment: Back to the starting situation.

Comment: now comment other `RewriteRule` and retry. Also post your root .htaccess in your question.

Comment: I have removed anything extra - one 1 line .htaccess in root, in dir: your 2 lines (commented out rewrites) plus 6 original ones. Still 403 for www.example.com/dir, with trailing slash it works fine.

Comment: Hmm that means you don't have `DirectorySlash On` in root .htaccess

Comment: With that one line in root .htaccess, is `www.example.com/dir` not becoming `www.example.com/dir/` in browser?

Comment: I have "DirectorySlash On" in root and it's working (when I remove .htaccess from dir, www.example.com/dir displays directory listing). I believe in some way "Order Deny,Allow" is blocking everything we try.

Comment: But how come you still have `Order Deny,Allow` block? My suggested code was supposed to replace all the `Order Deny,Allow` code you showed in question.

Comment: You also need to to remove all the `FilesMatch` block.

Comment: Oh, I mentioned twice that I have put your lines first, then the ones from question. The F flag makes the trick, I'd rather not say what F-word I mean right now. I always have public directory and don't bother with similar problems, this time I had to. Thank you very much for your help! (could you explicitly write in your original answer to remove rules from a question in case anyone else will read it?)

Comment: You're welcome, Glad it worked out. I have updated question accordingly.